# Can I make so the computer treat a ip as 127.0.0.1?

Tags: networking

I'm a software developer, and I sometimes take my work home. However, every time I do that I need to change the ip addresses my software connects to from let 172.28.38.270 to 127.0.0.1. I have tried to change it in the host file by doing this `127.0.0.1    172.28.38.270` but for some reason that don't work, it still tried to connect to 172... and not to 127... when I used to 172... ip.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? or do I just have to keep changing ip?

Comment: Why not connect to 127.0.0.1 at work also?

Comment: Because at work I need to program to be "live" and therefor it need to be connected to my jobs server instead of the local computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, 172.28.38.270 is not a valid ip. If you want some ip to redirect to your localhost, simply setup a virtual interface and associate it with the ip you want redirected:

```
#ifconfig eth0:0 172.28.2.1/24
```

Comment: I know the IP looks strange, but it is a valid one that leads to my works local server. Anyway, thanks your answer ended up solving my problem.

Comment: @Yemto It is **not** a valid IP address. The possible addresses are 172.28.38.0 /24 (172.28.38.0 ~ 172.28.38.255). The last octet **cannot be > 255**

Comment: oh, I saw that now. sorry I must have typed it in wrong. But that shouldn't really matter for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this is to use a hostname instead of an IP to reference the remote PC. Then you just need to add an entry to your [host files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) on both machines which you use. IOW, use `myfancydnsname.int` in the hostname field of your client application instead of `172.28.38.270`. This will allow you to manage all of this at the location on the TCP\IP stack which you are, most likely, interested in.

Host files no do not provide a mechanism for creating IP aliases (they modify hostnames which is an altogether higher level on the stack than that). To do what you want differs by OS\setup. Here are some examples of how to [create a true IP alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944860/how-to-create-an-ip-alias-on-windows):

```
#Linux
sudo ifconfig en1 inet 33.33.33.33/32 alias

#Windows
netsh interface ip add address "Local Area Connection" 33.33.33.33 255.255.255.255
```

As you can see, these both work by simply adding another IP to your current interface. So you'd be replacing `33.33.33.33` with the IP which you'd like to pretend to be (`172.28.38.270`). The downside is that this IP must be valid on both networks. That means I've given you a solution to your problem only if you don't mind changing the rest of your network to match this new subnet. How else would you expect it to work though? Think about it, if you're going to mimick another IP then that IP must be valid on the network before a router is going to know what to do with it.

If you have a virtual machine installed, you can get around this somewhat by using a virtual adapter. This will allow you to mimick an entire subnet, thus bypassing the requirement to make your current subnet into something compatible.